# Firebase Security: read and write access from data values

Tags: security, firebase, firebase-security

I'm building a simple data structure and I'm hoping the Firebase security rules can accommodate it.

Right now I'm getting `PERMISSION_DENIED` for **read privileges**.

I know you're usually supposed to design your data structure around the security rules but there are **very specific reasons** for this data structure
So I'd like to try and make the security rules work around it.

Here's the json export of my data:

```
{
  "form" : {
    "form" : {
      "data" : "Form",
      "owner" : "116296988270749049875",
      "public" : true
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "116296988270749049875" : {
      "data" : "Daniel Murawsky"
    }
  }
}
```

And here's what I've got for the security rules so far:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "$form":{
          "$dataId":{
            ".read": "data.child('public').val() == true",
            ".write": "data.child('owner').val() == auth.uid"
          }
        }
    }
}
```

I've never seen a use case for having two `$location` variables, one after another, so I can imagine that being the problem. Any input is welcome.
Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Frank's recomendation to use the security simulator  (https://.firebaseio.com/?page=Simulator), I quickly figured out the problem with a little bit of play. Thanks Frank!

I didn't understand (even though I read it a dozen times) the concept that [Rules Cascade](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-cascade). Once I got it, it was easy.

Comment: Works for me: `new Firebase('https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/29297747/form/form').once('value', function(s) { console.log(s.val()); })` vs `new Firebase('https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/29297747/users/116296988270749049875').once('value', function(s) { console.log(s.val()); })`. Can you set up a similar reproduction?

Comment: The security simulator in the Firebase dashboard also gives a clear explanation of why these reads fail. If you haven't tried the simulator, it might be a good next stop. Meanwhile, I've re-enabled global reads on the Firebase I used for testing; otherwise too many existing fiddles will not work anymore.

Comment: Thank you Frank! As soon as I got into the security simulator, everything started to make sense very quickly. I've got it now!

Comment: Great that you figured it out. The cascading effect of rules is indeed one of the trickier parts of it. Do you think you can write your findings up in an answer? Self-answering is encouraged on StackOverflow and it would probably be helpful to others to learn what the problem was.

Comment: Indeed, please contribute your findings back to the community.